# Autocomplete table names are not showing up

Tags: sql-server, ssms, ssms-2012

My tables suggestions aren't populating when writing select statements. This only happens when I'm using my work VPN. How can I get the table name suggestions to appear?

My thought was that it would be network related, but my internet speed is very fast so I'm not sure what could be bottle-necking the issue if that is the problem.

I've already tried refreshing the tables, and messing with the autocomplete and intellisense settings.

Expect: populated list of tables as suggestions based on query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSMS intellisence has always been flaky. You've already done everything that can be done to force its hand. It may be better with newer versions (aside from interacting with SSIS, newer versions of SSMs will work perfectly fine with older releases of SQL Server), so give that a try. It'll install in parallel with your current version so there's no risk.

Comment: Adding that [Azure Data Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/azure-data-studio/download) is another option, albeit not an SSMS replacement.

Comment: Try telling that to Microsoft @DanGuzman... I really wish that wouldn't keep badging SSMS and ADS as products that can do the same thing when they really don't. :(

Comment: @Larnu I haven't heard anyone from Microsoft claiming that they have feature parity (@DanGuzman didn't imply that either). They're certainly _working on_ it, but they're pretty open about the fact that it's best suited to T-SQL developers and not DBAs right now.

Comment: It's more that it was SQL Operations Studio, it was badged as the replacement for SSMS on Linux that bugs me @alroc, and that there's no sign of a SSMS for Linux as yet.

Comment: @Larnu, there's both overlap and distinct features of each tool and I don't expect we'll see "one tool to rule them all" anytime soon. I use both of these free tools nowadays (one can launch ADS directly from SSMS) depending on the task.